# How do you sort an array based on more than one field in C?

Tags: c, sorting, date

I have an array of events, and I would like to sort them based on their year, then by month for each year, then by day for each month, then by hour for each day.

```
typedef struct {
    struct tm start;
    struct tm end;
} event;
...
event events[100];
```

I only need to worry about sorting with the `start` date. I've been struggling with this for hours...

Comment: You start by reading about the standard library function [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort).

Comment: I've looked at it before, I just had no idea how to use a function as a parameter like it calls for. I got it now though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same way you do *any* sorting on multiple keys: one at a time, in your desired order of priority.

A [`qsort()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort) callback could look something like this:

```
static int event_compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
  const event *ae = a, *be = b;

  if(ae->start.tm_year < be->start.tm_year)
    return -1;
  else if(ae->start.tm_year > be->start.tm_year)
    return 1;
  /* Years are equal, try to solve that by checking month. */
  if(ae->start.tm_month < be->start.tm_month)
    return -1;
  else if(ae->start.tm_month > be->start.tm_month)
    return 1;
  /* Months are equal, go on with day, and so on. */
}
```