# 2d Array Sorting by Column in C

Tags: c, sorting, multidimensional-array, columnsorting

I have the code below that can produce

```
[p18d541@csci112 program1]$ ./main 17 < inp17.txt
 12 25 110 168
 35 64 113 134
 91 158 183 217
 102 129 130 146
 26 116 215 223
 0 78 81 162
 19 25 204 222
 124 138 157 245
 137 183 201 249
 61 67 106 236
 60 71 106 236
 63 81 106 240
 14 27 111 168
 17 27 111 168
 26 116 215 220
 111 137 202 249
 111 137 202 246
```

from an input of

```
 168.12.110.25
 64.113.134.35
 217.158.91.183
 102.130.129.146
 215.116.26.223
 81.162.78.0
 19.204.25.222
 245.124.138.157
 137.249.183.201
 106.61.236.67
 106.71.236.60
 106.81.240.63
 168.14.111.27
 168.17.111.27
 215.116.26.220
 137.249.111.202
 137.246.111.202
```

so my code scans in the input stores the values in network
and then I need to arrange them by the column from least to greatest starting at the first number and working its way to the right. an example of a the first few would be

```
0 78 81 162
12 25 110 168
14 27 111 168
.
.
.

111 137 202 246
111 137 202 249
.
.
.
```

.

```
//declare libraries

 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 //declare other functions/files to be used in the program
 void print_fun(void);
 int sort_fun(int arg, unsigned char networks[arg][4]);
 void read_fun(void);


 //read command line input and store the information
 int main(int argc, char** argv){
     //declar variable
     int arg = 0;

     //make argv into an int
     arg = atoi(argv[1]);
     //assign size to networks
      unsigned char networks[arg][4];

   //assign input to networks
     for (int j =0; j<1; ++j){
         if(argc == 1)
              {
                 printf("ERROR ERROR, you messed up\n");
             }

         else
         {
         // hold network addresses in a 2-d array, with 4 nsigned char

             for(int k = 0; k<arg; k++){
                 for (int i =0; i<4; i++){

                 scanf("%hhu.", &networks[k][i]);
                 //checks to see if scanf was working roperly
                // printf(" %hhu",networks[k][i]);

             }
                //printf("\n");
             }}}

             sort_fun(arg, networks);
 //sort array

 //count networks

 //print info about the array
 return(0);
}

 int sort_fun(int arg, unsigned char networks[arg][4]){
     //declaring variabes

 //sorting by comlumn p
     for (int k = 0; k < arg; k++){
         for( int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
             for (int j = i+1; j<4; ++j){
                 if (networks[k][i] > networks[k][j]) {
                     int swap = networks[k][i];
                     networks[k][i] = networks[k][j];
                     networks[k][j] = swap;
                 }
             }
         }
    }

for (int i =0; i<arg; i++){
     for (int j =0; j < 4; j++){
         printf(" %hhu", networks[i][j]);
         }
         printf("\n");
         }
 return(0);
 }
```

I have tried switching around the variables in my for loop and messing with the values, but I cannot seem to figure out how to change my code to work in columns instead of rows.

and by the way each value is stored in a separate array element but they need to stick together like in the input, so when one number moves the whole line moves with it. please let me know what you think. thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by *"arrange them by column"*? What is the expected output that you actually want?

Comment: I added a clarification, please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Ok, so [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265098/). This basic idea is that the comparison involves multiple keys. In your case, there are four keys which are the four fields of the IP address. It helps to write a compare function, e.g. `int compare(int addr1[4], int addr2[4])`. The compare function should return -1 (less), 0 (equal) or 1 (greater). Start by comparing `addr1[0]` to `addr2[0]`. If they are **not** equal, then return -1 or 1 as appropriate. Otherwise, move to the next field. At the end, if all four fields are the same, return 0.

Comment: i don't really understand how that would work, i looked at the provided example but i don't understand how to so so with an array when it looked like the answer was using i single dimensional array and i don't understand how to translate that . unless i have to use a for loop instead of constants?

Comment: Think of the problem as sorting a one-dimensional array of IP addresses. The sort function needs two nested loops, e.g. using indexes `i` and `j`. The elements of the 1D array are `networks[i]` and `networks[j]`. You need to be able to compare those elements, and swap them. So write a `compare` function, and a `swap` function. Call the `compare` function like `result = compare(networks[i], networks[j])`. Call the `swap` function like `swap(networks[i], networks[j])`. Once you have the functions that can compare and swap IP addresses, the sorting code is exactly the same as sorting a 1D array.